# Elegant Method to Validate Submitted Foreign Keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, validation, binding, model

I have lately read several articles and questions about Model Binding and Validation in asp.net MVC. What i have missed so far was the validation of a given foreign key id (drop-down list of related items for example).

If we consider the following situation:

There is an Entity (i.e. a Website Area) that features a set of folders, and the user is allowed to put entries into that folder, but only into the folders belonging to the Website Area the user has access to.

So what could be an elegant method to validate if the given foreign key value belongs to the set of folders that belong to the Website Area in question?

I assume it would be smart to perform this check by using a custom Model Binder and or a custom Validator which has access to the data repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just let the database do its work and let it validate FK's. In your controller you can handle the error and display back to view as you see fit.

Comment: the problem was not the FK constraint in its pure nature (as you are right in that case) but rather an access control issue when only offering a subset of options specific to a special kind of parent entity (i.e. only line positions specific to exactly this invoice or whatever). but i think i can transfer your idea. considering that a direct manipulation - working arround the user interface - is not an expected use-case and therefore an exception raised by the model / database layer would be suitable.